# Does there exist a form of Pythagorean quadruples gives that they are relatively prime?

Tags: algorithms

I am working on how to find the Frobenius number of Pythagorean quadruples. In this problem we have
$$a=m^2+n^2-p^2-q^2\\
b=2(mq+np)\\
c=2(nq-mp)\\
d=m^2+n^2+p^2+q^2\\
a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2$$
Where $m, n, p, q, a, b, c, d$ are all non-negative integers.
And I would like to find conditions on the integers $m,n,p,q$ that would ensure $\gcd (a,b,c,d)=1$.

Ps: Obviously there exist the situation that the four numbers are relatively prime but they are not fit in the form of $a, b, c, d$.

Answer (score 0):

The additional condition is that $m+n+p+q \equiv 1 \pmod 2,$  which means $m+n+p+q$ must be odd. That is all